# Skipped 104 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I checked across StackOverflow for answers, but I did not find much. So, I am doing this for practice, like Hello World for working with JSON, I am getting JSON response from openweather API.
I write the name of the city in EditText and press the button to search for it and display JSON string in the logs.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText city;
public void getData(View view){
    String result;
    String cityName = city.getText().toString();
    getWeather weather = new getWeather();
    try {
        result = weather.execute(cityName).get();
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class getWeather extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        String result = "";

        try {
            String finalString = urls[0];
            finalString = finalString.replace(" ", "%20");
            String fullString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + finalString + "&appid=a18dc34257af3b9ce5b2347bb187f0fd";
            url = new URL(fullString);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            while(data != -1){
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
}
}
```

What can I do to not get that message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`weather.execute(cityName).get()`

When you do `get()` you are waiting the AsyncTask to finish. Thus you are running all heavy operation on Ui thread.

From [documentation of get()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()):

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

Remove `get()`.

Comment: Adding to this-  never call .get().  The point of an AsyncTask is to run in parallel.  If you feel the need to call ,get(), there was no point to using an AsyncTask in the first place.  And doing so on the UI thread is an absolute no, you're making your entire app unresponsive and may get it killed by the watchdog timer.  The number of times .get is appropriate are very limited.

Comment: Okay, but if I remove .get() I get an error 'Incompatile types'.. So what do I use instead of .get(), or is there a better way to get JSON data?

Comment: Should I use onPostExecute() ?

Comment: @VedranKorponajić, yes, all the logic that should be done upon successful background job finish should be done in `onPostExecute()`.